# Ubuntu 16.04 TLS Can Not Connect To Windows 7 Or XP Shares, But Windows 7 And XP PCs Can Connect To Ubuntu Share

Tags: ubuntu, windows, smb

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 TLS on my laptop. Have Windows 7 Professional PC and several Windows XP PCs. Never had an issue accessing any Windows share on any Windows PC from any other Windows PC.

Using basic network--workgroup, no domain, no Active Directory.

I installed SAMBA on Ubuntu and created a very simple SMB.CONF file, shown here:

```
[global]
workgroup = SAMBADOM
server string = Ubuntu
security = user

[printers]
comment = printer section
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes

[share]
comment = shared directory section
path = /home/richard/share
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
create mask = 0777
```

Of course restarted the SMBD and NMBD services.

When I go to either my Windows 7 PC or XP PC, in the Network section I can see the workgroup SAMBADOM, and I see all my PCs, and my Ubuntu laptop. And from any of the Windows PCs I can open the Ubuntu laptop, see the share, and place files in the share. If I then open the share on the Ubuntu laptop I see the files. I can perform any file operations on the files in the Ubuntu share from either Ubuntu or the Windows PCs.

Now, the other way around, when I use Ubuntu's Files application, I can see all the Windows PCs and the Ubuntu laptop in the Network under the workgroup SAMBADOM. Unfortunately, when I click on one of the Windows PCs to open it, and the Ubuntu dialog box appears asking for username and password, when I enter the Windows PC's username and password, and press (I think it's) the Connect button, the dialog box simply "resets". I can try over-and-over for any Windows PC and the results are the same--can't connect.

The short version of all this is that I can access my Ubuntu share from any Windows PCs, but I can't access any Windows PCs from my Ubuntu laptop.

Interestingly, if I use the smbclient in a terminal on the Ubuntu laptop I can access the Windows PCs and the shared folders on them. Just does not seem to work through the GUI.

I've checked my firewall on the Windows PCs and ensured that the proper ports are open. I even disabled the firewalls temporarily--this did not help.

BTW. This is an Ubuntu workstation install on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Not sure if this helps. When I upgraded samba from 3.x to 4.x, my scripts with `net rpc` commands quit working. The reason was a default changed in the smb.conf. Under `[global]` I had to add `client ipc signing = disabled`. (http://pastebin.com/ghiT4sSV)

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after performing many different things including re-installing Ubuntu and editing the SMB.CONF file I figured out how to fix my issue.

I wiped my laptop clean and installed Fedora 24 Workstation and noticed the same results--HMMMM I said.

And then I realized that most of the computers I was trying to connect to had usernames, of course, but blank passwords. I tried as SMB.CONF edit that someone had mentioned to allow the use of blank passwords but was not able to get that to work. And, as needed, I would always re-start my smbd and nmbd after changes.

Anyway, I did have one computer on the network that has a username and password. Guess what--from Fedora I was able to connect! Then I entered passwords on the other computers and presto, was able to finally connect to them from Fedora.

Now, since the goal is to use Ubuntu I again wiped my laptop clean but this time again did a fresh install of Ubuntu workstation. I made two very minor changes to the SMB.CONF file (made these also on the Fedora install) to set the workgroup name properly and the netbios name properly. Just left everything else default.

Next, shared a folder on the Ubuntu machine. Simply used the GUI to share the folder out (did not modify the SMB.CONF) and set it to allow guest access. Now, every PC on my network can connect to the share on my Ubuntu machine. If I want to place tighter controls on who can and can't access that share I can make changes in my SMB.CONF.

But now, to the best part--now I can connect from my Ubuntu laptop to any of other computers and shares on my network.

The solution to my problem, which may or may not help others, is that those devices I could not connect to had accounts without passwords. Once passwords were assigned all worked.

Hope this can help someone!

Thanks,

Rich Huelbig